# Justification for solution of Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, wiener-measure

If I have a Stochastic Differential Equation such as:

$dX_t=(W_{t}^{3}+t^2)dt-2dW_t $ with $X_0$=$1$

and

$dX_t=(W_t+t)dt+W_{t}^{2}dW_t $ with $X_0$=$1$

I would not be looking for the solution.

However, how would I justify **if or if** not a formula for $X_t$ exists of the form $X_t = f(t,W_t)$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: These are not SDE, these are stochastic quadrature problems. Can you tell a little more on the motivation of this question, why you do consider this form of equations?

Comment: The book I am working from states them as stochastic differential equation so I'm a bit confused. My motivation is simply to understand the method for the future as the book does not contain solutions.

Comment: Yes, they are SDE in the same sense that $f'(x)=x$ is an ODE. As the Ito integrals depend on the whole history of $W_s$, $s\in[0,t]$, which can be quite different for the same value of $W_t$, your goal is not achievable in general.

Comment: These are indeed not SDE. You already have the closed form for $X_t$ in both cases. Indeed, $$dX_t=(W_t^3+t^2)dt-2dW_t$$ is just a notation to write $$X_t=1+\int_0^t (W_s^3+s^2)ds-2W_t.$$ Same for the second equation.